# tbb::concurrent_hash_map - need help getting started

Tags: c++, hash, intel, tbb

I'm trying to get started with TBB.

I want to implement a concurrent hash map (concurrent_hash_map)

It should be keyed with a long int and return a char*...

Here's the code I have sofar:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#include "tbb/concurrent_hash_map.h"

using namespace tbb;
using namespace std;

typedef concurrent_hash_map<long int,char*> table;

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
   /*what to do here?*/
   /*How do I check if key present/add/remove entries to the hash, table?*/
   return 0;
}
```

Please bear in mind that I'm quite new to C++... I've been struggling on this for over an hour. I've read the following links:

http://www.devx.com/cplus/Article/33334/1763/page/2

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656329/how-to-lock-the-whole-concurrent-hash-map-not-warping-a-portion-of-code-with-mut

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

I got this example from the documentation:

```
#include "tbb/concurrent_hash_map.h"
#include "tbb/blocked_range.h"
#include "tbb/parallel_for.h"
#include <string>

using namespace tbb;
using namespace std;
// Structure that defines hashing and comparison operations for user's type.
struct MyHashCompare {
    static size_t hash( const string& x ) {
        size_t h = 0;
        for( const char* s = x.c_str(); *s; ++s )
            h = (h*17)^*s;
        return h;
    }
    //! True if strings are equal
    static bool equal( const string& x, const string& y ) {
        return x==y;
    }
};
// A concurrent hash table that maps strings to ints.
typedef concurrent_hash_map<string,int,MyHashCompare> StringTable;
// Function object for counting occurrences of strings.
struct Tally {
    StringTable& table;
    Tally( StringTable& table_ ) : table(table_) {}
    void operator()( const blocked_range<string*> range ) const {
        for( string* p=range.begin(); p!=range.end(); ++p ) {
            StringTable::accessor a;
            table.insert( a, *p );
           a->second += 1;
        }
    }
};
const size_t N = 1000000;
string Data[N];
void CountOccurrences() {
    // Construct empty table.
    StringTable table;
    // Put occurrences into the table
    parallel_for( blocked_range<string*>( Data, Data+N, 1000 ),
    Tally(table) );
    // Display the occurrences
    for( StringTable::iterator i=table.begin(); i!=table.end(); ++i )
        printf("%s %d\n",i->first.c_str(),i->second);
}
```

[edit: author's solution is moved out as community wiki answer]

Comment: There is a [documentation](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/documentation.php) for this. Download and read, both the tutorial and reference documents. And since you are new to C++ you may get used to work with STL containers.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/ver.php?fid=91

Comment: Yes, I've read the documentation, but I can't make any sense of it. Post edited.

Comment: "Over an hour" is not too much actually. Later in your career, there will be times were struggle over a problem for days or even weeks. Also note that you are not _implementing_ a concurrent hash map, but rather using one.

Comment: Yes, this is true. I got it working in the end. Post updated.

Answer (score 2):

Got it working now:

```
...
#include "tbb/concurrent_hash_map.h"

using namespace tbb;
using namespace std;

typedef concurrent_hash_map<long int,char*> data_hash;

int main(){
        data_hash dh;
        data_hash::accessor a;

        long int k=10;
        dh.insert(a,k);
        a->second="hello";
        for(data_hash::iterator j=dh.begin();j!=dh.end(); ++j){
                printf("%lu %s\n",j->first,j->second);
        }
        if(dh.find(a,9)){
                printf("true\n");
        }else{
                printf("false\n");      
        }
        a.release();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Though, this code is not suppose to do anything useful except demonstrating the API, it has 2 potential problems which **must not be copy-pasted**.

 1. The `a` accessor is not released after the update (`a->second="hello"`) and holds the lock to the element while doing the traverse via iterators.
 2. it's unsafe to mix iterators and concurrent methods in the same code since concurrent methods invalidate iterators

And an optimization hint:
the code above could use `count(9)` instead to avoid the overhead from locking the element in accessor.

Comment: How do you find a value with just the key? Say if I wanted to increment the value associated with the key (and I don't know the old value)?

Comment: Please refer to the documentation. Use find() or insert(), then use accessors to get to the value

Comment: I don’t see a version of find that takes only the key, am I missing something?

Comment: there is count(); which returns 0 or 1 (if found) for a given key, i.e. checks for existance of a key. If you want to access the value, you need the accessor, which goes to insert() and find() arguments